# Short Term Tourist Visa Refusal

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

As my girlfriend who is a permanent resident of Germany invited me to come to her country for a short visit, I applied to the visa section in Kolkata. As I am a first time visitor to Germany I got all information and submitted the forms along with "Formal Obligation Letter" and as I am a self employed I did not need to submit employers certificate. To my utter surprise, my visa was refused stating that:

> the information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and condition of the intended stay was not reliable

and

> your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained

Now in this situation what should I do when already 5 days passed that my visa was refused? Should I reapply stating my willingness to return back to my home country before the visa expire or should I submit any evidence to justify the two reasons? Please suggest after how many days is it better to reapply? Can I get my visa approved if I can produce my justification with a proof?

Comment: Did your gf's invitation offer accommodation that she owns or rents? If rented, did she include a statement from the landlord? If owned, did she include the property deed?  Just asking...

Comment: Did you provide proof of ties to your home country, and include things that show you're likely to return? As it stands, it looks like your visa was rejected as they fear you're remain in Germany with your girlfriend instead of leaving

Comment: There is no waiting period. If you can address these issues with additional documentation, you can apply again tomorrow.

Comment: IMO, you will continue to have difficulties. You are self-employed, so have no outside firm pulling you back to India, your girlfriend is already a permanent resident in Germany; those two facts would add up to going to Germany and having no pressing reason to return to your homeland. Which is exactly what was meant by their statement number 2.

Comment: If you can show that you have work waiting for you when you return to India, that would address their inability to ascertain your intention to leave the territory of the Member States.  As to the reliability of the information you provided, it's hard to address that without knowing why they considered it unreliable.  Perhaps you can find out, but I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

You generally need to show evidence of a return flight to gain entry.  It happened to me before on a business trip and i ended up spending an extra $4000 on an open return.